# How do we handle empty forms in Flask?

Tags: python, forms, flask

I've written an app that reads data from a csv file and displays the student id and course id and their marks. I am having difficulty in handling situations when no buttons are selected and no text written and submit is pressed or when something is written in text field and no buttons are selected and submit is pressed.
Flask should render error.html in both of the above situations but I am getting a bad request error.

Please see the below code

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask, request
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def read_csv():# Function to read csv
    student_dic = {}
    courses = []

    file = open("./data.csv")
    count = 0
    a = file.readlines()
    for line in a:

        r = line.split(",")
        if r[1] not in courses:
            courses.append(r[1].strip())
        r[2] = r[2].rstrip()
        if count == 0:
            count = count + 1
            continue

        if (r[0]) in student_dic:

            k = {}
            k[(r[1].strip())] = int(r[2])
            student_dic[(r[0])].update(k)



        else:

            student_dic[(r[0])] = {(r[1].strip()): int(r[2])}

    return ([student_dic, courses])


def plot_hist(marks_list):# Function to plot
    plt.hist(marks_list)
    plt.savefig("./static/hist.png")
    plt.close()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("index.html")

    elif request.method == "POST":
        option = request.form["ID"]
        print("here",option)
        dic, courses = read_csv()
        if option == "student_id":
            user_input = (request.form["id_value"])

            if user_input == '':
                return render_template("error.html")
            else:

                if user_input in dic:
                    student_id_dic = dic[user_input]
                    total_marks = sum(student_id_dic.values())

                    return render_template("student_details.html", course_id_data=student_id_dic,
                                           student_id_data=user_input,
                                           total_marks_data=total_marks)
                else:
                    return render_template("error.html")

        elif option == "course_id":
            user_input_course = request.form["id_value"]
            if user_input_course == '':
                return render_template("error.html")
            else:

                if user_input_course in courses:
                    ct = 0
                    max_marks = -1
                    total = 0
                    mark_list = []
                    h = 0
                    for student_id in dic:

                        for key, value in dic[student_id].items():

                            if key == user_input_course:
                                mark_list.append(value)
                                ct = ct + 1
                                total = total + value
                                if value > max_marks:
                                    max_marks = value
                    plot_hist(mark_list)
                    return render_template("course_details.html", average_marks=(total / ct), maximum_marks=max_marks,
                                           img='./static/hist.png')

                else:
                    return render_template("error.html")

        return render_template("error.html")
    return render_template("error.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    app.debug = True
```

Here is the index html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Enter Details</title>
 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Enter the details</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/" id = "data-form">
        <input type="radio" name="ID" value="student_id" />
        <label>Student ID</label>
        <input type="radio" name="ID" value="course_id" />
        <label>Course ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id_value" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

   
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Something Went Wrong</title>
 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Wrong Inputs</h1>
    <p> Something went wrong  </p>
        <br>

        <a href="/">Go Back</a>

    </div>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solved this by using request.form.get()

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be better handled using [form validators](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/), rather than adding logic in the route and custom error pages. If you don't want users to submit the form without certain information, just make it impossible to do (using validators). This will also be a better user experience, since they won't have to click "Go Back" on the error page.

You can use built-in validators, such as DataRequired, and you can also write custom validation functions.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that when nothing is selected keys will not be there used request.form.get("ID"). request.form.get() is to be used when were are unsure whether the key exists.